# Wrapper component executing the inside code even the condition is false

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have this wrapper component

```
const AccessControl = ({ content, children }: acProps) => {
  return content ? children : null;
};
```

And I have used it like this

```
<AccessControl content={false}>
  {console.log("Ashish")}
  <div>This is executing</div>
</AccessControl>
```

So it is executing the children even the content is false. If this is how it works, how can I use a wrapper component to avoid ternary operators?

Answer (score 0):

JS evaluates its arguments before calling a function, including JSX expressions before they are passed as children to a component - which is why with `content={false}` the `<div>This is executing</div>` is not showing up, yet you can still see the `console.log`.

To get around this you can pass `children` as a function like this:

```
<AccessControl content={false}>
  {() => (
    <>
      {console.log("Ashish")}
      <div>This is executing</div>
    </>
  )}
</AccessControl>
```

and call `children` in `AcessControl` component (remember to change type in `acProps` from `ReactNode` to `() => ReactNode`)

```
const AccessControl = ({ content, children }: acProps) => {
  return content ? children() : null;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your wrapper component does do its job, the children won't be rendered to the DOM, it's just that functions inside a component will be run when it is rendered, which is why the console.log is running.

But a better way to go about this is to just conditionally render it via short circuiting.

`{content && (<div>This is executing</div>)}`

Answer (score 0):

You can **refactor** the component into a **wrapper** component that takes multiple children and renders them based on their type. This approach is based on the concept of compound components, which are a pattern for creating more flexible and reusable components.

Example:

```
const AccessControl = ({ children }) => {
 const renderChildren = useCallback(() => {
   return React.Children.map(children, (child) => {
     if (child?.type === AccessControl.Content && child.props.condition) {
       return child.props.children;
     }
     return null;
   });
 }, [children]);

 return <>{renderChildren()}</>;
};

AccessControl.Content = ({ children, condition }) => children;
```

In the above code, The `AccessControl` is a wrapper component that takes multiple children. It uses the `React.Children.map` function to iterate over its children and render them based on their type and a *condition prop*.

The `AccessControl.Content` component is a special child component that takes a *condition prop* and its own children. If the *condition prop* is truthy, it renders its children; otherwise, it renders null.

After that, you can use this refactored `AccessControl` component like this:

```
<AccessControl>
 <AccessControl.Content condition={content}>
   {children}
 </AccessControl.Content>
</AccessControl>
```

This will allows you to avoid using a <strike>ternary operator</strike> and makes your code more flexible and maintainable. It also provides a clear and explicit way to control the rendering of different parts of your component.

This is a suggestion, so if not usefull, please tell me so I will remove this answer immediately. :)

Answer (score 0):

Because it's an *inline code* and always runs despite of condition it `true` or `false`.

In React typically we use inline code only for **conditional rendering**. You can't use any business logic there if you want try this.

```
const AccessControl = ({ content, children }) => {
  if(content){
    console.log("I am rendering");
    //logic
    return children;
  }
};
```

Or even better without any logic just for rendering like this

```
{content && (<div>This is executing</div>)}
```

Using Children is uncommon and can lead to fragile code [More on](https://react.dev/reference/react/Children)